# List all EC2 Instances - AWSCLI

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, unix, aws-cli

I want to list all ec2 instances for each account we have on ~/.aws/credentials, but the `aws ec2 describe-instances` doesn't return anything.

```
ACC=$(cat ~/.aws/credentials | egrep "\[.*\]" | cut -d '[' -f2 | cut -d ']' -f1 | grep -v default | sort)
FILE="${HOME}/ec2.csv"

echo -e "ACCOUNT;EC2" > ${FILE}

for account in ${ACC}
do
    for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --profile default --region sa-east-1 --output text | cut -f3)
    do
        EC2=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --profile ${account} --region ${region} --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].{PrivateIP:PrivateDnsName,Name:Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value,Status:State.Name}" --output text)
        echo -e "${account};${EC2}" >> ${FILE}
    done
done
```

Comment: Have you exported the credentials?

Comment: @RamanSailopal yes, the account loop works fine, but the region dont, i tried creating a file regions and looping through this file and i receive Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://ec2./root/region.amazon.aws.com, it seems the region looping doesnt work, and im looking for alternatives to run this job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this issue replacing the default profile on the second `for`.

```
for region in $(aws ec2 describe-regions --profile ${account} --region sa-east-1 --output text | cut -f3)
```

This script works, i hope this script can help's.